# I want my carousel to be appeared in index page only in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carousel

I am new to rails and I want my carousel code to be seen in the index page only,please give a solution and below is my code :

```
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/navigation'%>
  <%= render 'layouts/carousel' %>
  <%= render 'layouts/messages'%>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <%= yield %>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just add the code in index page instead of layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you'd want the move any code that's specific to a page out of the layout and into the template for the appropriate action.

However, in your case that piece of code looks embedded within the rest of the page skeleton so it could be hard to refactor it that way.

For this reason I'd suggest using conditional rendering by simply using a Boolean variable.

For example you could do:

```
<%= render 'layouts/carousel' if @render_carousel %>
```

And then you could just set the `@render_carousel` variable to `true` for any action that you'd want the carousel to appear in, e.g.:

```
def index
    # rest of the code
    @render_carousel = true
end
```

Comment: @anna97 Glad to hear it's working for you. If you're satisfied with the solution, then please click on the check mark on the left to let others know that this issue was resolved.